# Consulta en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

hago esta consulta:

```
$costo = Habitacion::where("id","=", $habestatus)->select('hab_costo')->first();
```

*Habestatus es una variable que tiene el id de la habitación.

y al imprimir el resultado me arroja esto:

```
{"hab_costo":2000}
```

Yo solo quiero el numero como resultado.

Comment: solo es de hacer lo siguiente `$costo->hab_costo` si mal no recuerdo

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente me faltaba eso! mil gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo quieres el valor de hab_costo, puedes hacer varias cosas:

- Obtener la propiedad directamente:

  ```
  $costo = Habitacion::whereId($habestatus)
              ->select('hab_costo')
              ->first()
              ->hab_costo;
  ```
- No tan específico pero pluck también puede servir:

  ```
  $costo = Habitacion::whereId($habestatus)
              ->select('hab_costo')
              ->first()
              ->pluck('hab_costo');
  ```

Ten en cuenta que se puede reducir algo de código usando `whereVariable()`